# What is the Source for "Ekam EvA dviteeyam brahman" Mantra

Tags: scripture, mantras, sanskrit, source, shruti

I'm finding Source for "Ekam EvA dviteeyam brahman" Mantra.

Answer (score 2):

This verse can be found in one of the oldest Upanishads from the Sama Veda The Chandogya Upanishad 6.2.1 which states :

> सदेव सोम्येदमग्र आसीदेकमेवाद्वितीयम् । तद्धैक आहुरसदेवेदमग्र आसीदेकमेवाद्वितीयं तस्मादसतः सज्जायत ॥ ६.२.१ ॥

> sadeva somyedamagra āsīd**ekamevādvitīyam** | taddhaika āhurasadevedamagra āsīdekamevādvitīyaṃ tasmādasataḥ sajjāyata ||

A beautiful Commentary for the same by Acharya Shankar can be read [here](https://ia800301.us.archive.org/29/items/Shankara.Bhashya-Chandogya.Upanishad-Ganganath.Jha.1942.English/Shankara.Bhashya-Chandogya.Upanishad-Ganganath.Jha.1942.English.pdf)
(refer Page 311 Section 2 Verse 1)

Source for Sanskrit Verse can be found [here](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/chandogya-upanishad-english)

Comment: @Shiva Namah Why was my answer unaccepted after being accepted once?Could you pls clarify Sir?? If it is a mistake on my part maybe then i can modify the existing answer :)

Comment: @Shiva Namah Sir could u pls clarify?